# Stop/interrupt and close sftp connection in Expect script

Tags: linux, shell, ascii, sftp, expect

I have a Expect script that connects to a sftp server. Because the password for the sftp account is changed periodically. The Expect script has to be able to detect when the password that is being used fails and stop/ interrupt the connection.

So far my Expect script is working fine. I am interrupting the connection sending ctrl-c ( send \x03 ). But I found out this is not a correct way to stop or interrupt a sftp connection.

I saw that is a better practice to use ctrl-alt-u-x to stop the sftp connection.

How can I send  ctrl-alt-u-x in my Expect script?

Thanks

Comment: I wouldnt bother sending anything. Just exit from your expect script, or if you have other things to do in the script then use the command `close` to close the connection to the current process.

Comment: I think the ctrl-alt-u-x is a hotkey specific to the Sublime text editor when using sftp connection. I worry it will not work in a command line sftp controlled by expect.